# How to resolve undefined reference boost error in building pion network library?

Tags: c++, boost

I am getting below error while compiling pion network library in centos 7. I have installed boost 1.53.

error:

> make[1]: Entering directory
>   `/home/admin/pion-5.0.6/pion-5.0.6/utils' CXXLD helloserver
>
>   ../src/.libs/libpion.so: undefined reference to`   boost::
>   re_detail_106100 ::
>   cpp_regex_traits_implementation::transform(char const*, char
>   const*) const'         ../src/.libs/libpion.so: undefined reference to
>   `boost::thread_detail::rollback_once_region(boost::once_flag&)'
>   ../src/.libs/libpion.so: undefined reference to`
>   boost::re_detail_106100::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator,
>   std::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits >
>
> > ::construct_init(boost::basic_regex > > const&,
> >     boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)' ../src/.libs/libpion.so:
> >     undefined reference to
> >     `boost::thread_detail::commit_once_region(boost::once_flag&)'
> >     ../src/.libs/libpion.so: undefined reference to`
> >     boost::re_detail_106100::cpp_regex_traits_implementation::transform_primary(char const*, char const*) const' ../src/.libs/libpion.so: undefined
> >     reference to
> >     `boost::re_detail_106100::raise_runtime_error(std::runtime_error
> >     const&)' ../src/.libs/libpion.so: undefined reference to`
> >     boost::re_detail_106100::get_mem_block()' ../src/.libs/libpion.so:
> >     undefined reference to
> >     `boost::re_detail_106100::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)' ../src/.libs/libpion.so: undefined reference to`
> >     boost::re_detail_106100::put_mem_block(void*)'
> >     ../src/.libs/libpion.so: undefined reference to
> >     `boost::re_detail_106100::verify_options(unsigned int,
> >     boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)' ../src/.libs/libpion.so:
> >     undefined reference to`
> >     boost::thread_detail::enter_once_region(boost::once_flag&)' collect2:
> >     error: ld returned 1 exit status make[1]: *** [helloserver] Error 1
> >     make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/admin/pion-5.0.6/pion-5.0.6/utils'
> >     make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Please help me to sole this issue..